# Как изменить цвет одного столбца в наборе `QBarSet`?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt5, pyqt

Как изменить цвет одного столбца в наборе `QBarSet`.

Пример реализации

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import random

class MainWidow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800 ,500)
        series = self.append_series()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(series)
        self.chart.setTitle("Simple percentbarchart example")

        chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

    def append_series(self):
        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set0.append([random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(5)])
        series = QStackedBarSeries()
        series.append(set0)
        series.setBarWidth(1)
        return series

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = MainWidow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ожидаемый результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покликайте по столбцам QBarSet.

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import random

class MainWidow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 500)

        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.setTitle("Simple percentbarchart example")
        series = QBarSeries()                                 # QStackedBarSeries()   
        series.setBarWidth(1)

        for i in range(5):                      
            _set = self.append_series(i)
            series.append(_set)
        self.chart.addSeries(series)

        chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

    def append_series(self, i):
        _set = QBarSet(str(i))                                #("Min")
        _set.append(random.randint(1, 10))
        _set.clicked.connect(lambda _, i=i, s=_set: self.clickedBarSet(i, s))             
        _set.setColor(QColor("#800080"))

#        return series
        return _set

    def clickedBarSet(self, index, _set):
        if _set.color().name() == "#800080":
            _set.setColor(QColor("#008080"))
        else:
            _set.setColor(QColor("#800080"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = MainWidow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Реализация хорошоая но не совсем что нужно. Как изменить цвет отдельного елемента при рисовании столбцов (не кликом)?

Comment: @MiraSlav `клик` здесь ни при чем. Меняйте цвет при любом условии или событии.